# How can I pass dynamic value for p:remoteCommand ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I have a p:dataTable which contains p:commandLink. I need to do ajax call with parameters on mouseover event. I found that commandLink cant make ajax call by mouseover event. We have to use remotecommand for this functionality.

I prefered this solution-

[p:commandLink ajax events inside of a p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629425/pcommandlink-ajax-events-inside-of-a-pdatatable)

Its working nice. Since its inside dataTable, here we will get multiple remoteCommand. If I want to use single remotecommand for every ajax call of command link what I have to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you should call JavaScript function, created by `p:remoteCommand` with parameter which indicates you data (it can be for example primary key of your model bean or something with which you can identify object):

```
onmouseover="rc([{ name: 'myData', value: #{data.code} }])"
```

This will pass additional parameter named `muData` to you listener. You can obtain that parameter with this:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String code = map.get("myData").toString();
```

**See also:**

- [JSF PrimeFaces inputText inside dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991144/759126)